# Appdelegate function 'didreceivelocalnotification' is called immediately after the notification is created

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.3, uilocalnotification, appdelegate

I'm using `UILocalNotification`s in iPhone to create an alarm. Alarm is scheduled when I click a `UIButton`. My issue is that `– application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` is called when I click this button, that is when I create a local notification. But , `– application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` should be called only when the notification time is reached. I checked it on both simulator and device  and got the same results. Can anyone help me with this...thanks in advance.

```
-(void)createalarm:(NSString *)datend_time:(NSString *)message//creating alarm
{
NSLog(@"created!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
NSString *datestr = datend_time;
NSString *textstr = message;
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];    
NSDate *alerttime = [formatter dateFromString:datestr];
UIApplication * app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];    

UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (notification)
{
    notification.fireDate = alerttime;
    //notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notification.repeatInterval = 0;
    notification.alertBody = textstr;
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;        
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

    [app presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];          
}

}


-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:    (UILocalNotification *)notification
{
NSLOG(@"delegate called")    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you call

```
[app presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

So it shows the notification right after you created it. Remove this line of code.

`[app scheduleLocalNotification:notification]`; will work just fine and will shot the notification at fireDate.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of NSLocalnotification:

```
-(void) scheduleNotificationForDate: (NSDate*)date {

/* Here we cancel all previously scheduled notifications */
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.fireDate = date;
NSLog(@"Notification will be shown on: %@",localNotification.fireDate);

localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                              @"Your notification message"];
localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View details", nil);

/* Here we set notification sound and badge on the app's icon "-1" 
means that number indicator on the badge will be decreased by one 
- so there will be no badge on the icon */

localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Make sure that the date you are setting is not in the past!

Comment: I have already checked it. I,m sure that the date i'm setting is not in the past.